# Fail to copy file (access denied) even though I ran as admin

Tags: java, io

I'm trying to make an app that copies files from one drive to another, but for some reason, it keeps giving me an error saying I do not have permission to write even though I ran as admin and the account that is running this app is the only account on the device. I know I have permission to the destination because

1. A large number of files (out of n files) are able to copy to the destination successfully
2. I have given the user full permission to the directory
3. The destination is an external storage drive.
4. I can make a new file in that destination's directory

Additionally: I'm on windows 10

Copy function:

```
private void c2cTransfer(Path source, Path dest) throws Exception {
    // Get channel for output file
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dest.toFile());
    WritableByteChannel targetChannel = fos.getChannel();

    // Get channel for input files
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(source.toString());
    FileChannel inputChannel = fis.getChannel();

    System.out.print("Closing all IO readers...\t");
    // Transfer data from input channel to output channel
    inputChannel.transferTo(0, inputChannel.size(), targetChannel);

    // close the input channel
    inputChannel.close();
    fis.close();

    // finally close the target channel
    targetChannel.close();
    fos.close();
}
```

Where the function is being called:

```
        if (newPath.toFile().canWrite()) {
            c2cTransfer(f, newPath); // Start transfer
            System.out.printf("Complete!\n");
        } else {
            // Keep jumping to here.
            System.err.printf("Failed!\nYou do not have permission to write to: %s\n", newLocation);
            failedTransfer.add(f);
        }
```

Comment: Make sure you have access to both parts of the drive. The drive you're coping from and the drive that you want to paste in.

Comment: @AWellPlacedCactus I have and I do

Comment: Does the target file already exist at newPath?

Comment: Are you a) trying to write to a file that already exists b) writing to a file that has the same name as an existing directory c) trying to write a file with an unusual file name (ie. has control characters) d) have you run out of space on the destination drive?

Comment: You might try getting rid of the check newPath.toFile().canWrite() and just write it to see what Exception gets thrown.  Your code assumes you don't have permission if you can't write the file, but that might not be the reason.

Comment: @D.L The files that failed does not exist in the destination so far I would like it to write a new copy regardless of the existence or not. The name is nothing unusual (all save characters) and there are plenty of spaces. Additionally, I added that check because there was a weird bug weird it kept my io for the drive open when I failed to write.

Comment: Is it always the same file that fails, or is it different every time?

Comment: @D.L. Same fails, but I found the problem (though it's still failing on some files). The answer was to check if file exist, and if not call the .getParentFiles().mkdirs() follow by .createNewFile()

Comment: Ahh...  Yeah, writing to a directory that doesn't exist would be a problem.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the files needed to exist before hand, so my solution was this:

```
if (!newPath.toFile().exists()) {
    newPath.toFile().getParentFile().mkdirs();
    newPath.toFile().createNewFile();
}
```

Though I have one or two files that still giving me access denied even though it exist and I have full permission over it. So, I just made a override function that just deletes the old files and writes a new copy.